# Expand a child node of tree menu by default

Tags: html, css, menu

hi there I have a tree menu..

I want to open a node in the tree menu by default. 
I means when I refresh the page, a node of the menu will open by default.

for example extendend "Menu Am1b1" node by default in this example:

```
        jsfiddle.net/Friar_Broccoli/6LKc6/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be as easy as adding `checked="checked"` to a checkbox.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LKc6/52/)

Answer (score 0):

In your markup - just add th attribute 'checked' to your checkbox, like this:

```
<label class="menu_label" for="c5">Menu Bm0a1</label>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="c5" />
```

Your edited [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LKc6/53/)